# Preprocessor to repeat statements

Tags: arduino

I've just started working with Arduino. I seem to write code like this often:

```
int input_pins[] = {6, 3, 8, 2};
int input_state[4];

void setup() {                
}

void loop() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    input_state[i] = digitalRead(input_pins[i]); 
  }
}
```

Is there a preprocessor (or something like it) to produce the following effective code?

```
int input_state[4];

void setup() {                
}

void loop() {
  input_state[0] = digitalRead(6); 
  input_state[1] = digitalRead(3); 
  input_state[2] = digitalRead(8); 
  input_state[3] = digitalRead(2); 
}
```

Comment: #define a macro in your own header file?

Answer (score 0):

Arduino programming has C++ underneath, why do you want to use something as limited as preprocessing?

If you start out with the following code:

```
///////////////////////////////////////
class DigitalRead
{
public:
    DigitalRead(int pins[]);
    int operator[](const int index);
    int len;
    int *mypins;
};


DigitalRead::DigitalRead(int pins[])
{
   mypins = pins;
   for(len = 0; pins[len] != -1; len++) {};
}

int DigitalRead::operator[](const int index)
{
    if (index > len) return -1;
    return digitalRead(mypins[index]);
}
///////////////////////////////////////

int pins[] = {6, 3, 8, 2, -1};

DigitalRead input_state = DigitalRead(pins);

void setup()
{
}

void loop()
{
   // print the state of pin 6, change as needed
   Serial.println(input_state[0]);
}
```

you can improve on things (setting the pins for input in DigitalRead::DigitalRead e.g.)j. Once things work move the stuff between `///////` lines into a library.